# cummulative sum of a variable with condition

Tags: r

I have a problem in getting a running total of actual stock volume left with me. When the indicator shows `"Buy"`, it should add 100 and when the indicator shows `"Sell"`, it should subtract 100.

The problem is my stock volume left should add only when the next "Buy" signal
shows when its gone to 0....since I don't have any stocks to trade.

```
indicator   buy_sell_volume    actual_stock_volume_left
Buy         100                  100
Buy         100                  200
Hold         0                   200
Hold         0                   200
Sell       -100                  100
Sell       -100                   0
Sell       -100                   0
Sell       -100                   0
Sell       -100                   0
Buy         100                  100
Buy         100                  200
```

Comment: The table you shared, is that the expected output? Also, it'd help if you rephrase your problem as it's a bit unclear.

Comment: buy_sell_volume is basically stock volume....+100 means when i am buying 100 stocks from the market.....-100 means when i am selling back in the market.....indicator shows when to buy,sell or hold.....i have to do a cummulative sum of my actual volume  in which........if actual volume is 0 and sell indicator is sell,i can' sell the stock since my actual volume left is 0....and it should remain 0 until and unless indicator shows "buy"

Comment: see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have already encoded the `buy_sell_volume` field (`+` for Buy and `-` for Sell), you don't need any conditional calculations based on `indicator` field. Simple cumulative calculations will do.

```
# initialize new column
df$stock_volume_left <- NA

# assuming you start with 0 stocks, assign 1st value to stocks left
df$stock_volume_left[1] <- max(df$buy_sell_volume[1], 0)

# calculate stocks left 
for(i in 2:nrow(df)) {
  df$stock_volume_left[i] <- max(df$stock_volume_left[i-1] + df$buy_sell_volume[i], 0)
}

   indicator buy_sell_volume stock_volume_left
1        Buy             100               100
2        Buy             100               200
3       Hold               0               200
4       Hold               0               200
5       Sell            -100               100
6       Sell            -100                 0
7       Sell            -100                 0
8       Sell            -100                 0
9       Sell            -100                 0
10       Buy             100               100
11       Buy             100               200
```

Comment: thanxs a lot....i am just a beginner in r.....could you elaborate me what's max() doing in the above code....

Comment: it's just making sure that `stock_volume_left` is never negative. Run the code without `max` and see the difference.